# Linear Algebra Identity Matrix Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the following problem's solution, but just can't seem to grasp it.

[image: Identity matrix proof problem]

So I am having more difficulty understanding part 1.

I see that `ABX = A0 = 0` but I cannot see how you get to `x = IX = (I + AB)x = -(AB)x`

What I tried to do was assume `Bx = 0` and distribute as so:
`Ix + (AB)x = 0
 Ix + A(Bx) = 0
 Ix = 0`

But that does not lead to the conclusion I want: `Bx` is also non zero.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could walk me through this one. Thanks!

Comment: Suppose that $x$ is a nonzero solution to $(I + AB)x = 0$.  Then using the distributive property,

$$0 = (I + AB)x = Ix + (AB)x$$

Suppose by way of contradiction that $Bx = 0$.  Then also $(AB)x = A(Bx) = A(0) = 0$, by the associativity of matrix multiplication.  Therefore,

$$0 = Ix + (AB)x = Ix + 0 = Ix$$

Finally, $Ix = x$, so we get $0 = x$, contradiction.

Comment: @D_S Why is `Ix = x`? I thought x was a vector here, not a matrix.

Comment: I assume $I$ is the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix, and $x$ is a column vector ($n$ by $1$ matrix).  Check for yourself that the equation $Ix = x$ still holds.  For example, the case $n = 3$: $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @D_S very helpful thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since matrix multiplication distributes,
$$
(I + AB)x = Ix + ABx = x + ABx.
$$
The statement above is true for all $x$. Now let us consider a specific nonzero solution to $(I + AB)x=0$, call it $x^*$ and assume for the sake of a contradiction that $Bx^*=0$. Then
$$
(I + AB)x^* = x^* + ABx^* = x^* + A(Bx^*) = x^* + A\cdot 0 = x^*.
$$
But we know that $(I + AB)x^* = 0$ which leads to
$$
0 = (I +AB)x^* = x^*,
$$
and contradicts our assumption that $x^*$ is nonzero. It follows that our assumption that $Bx^*=0$ must be false.

Answer (score 1):

It's not $X=IX=(I+AB)X=-(AB)x$.

It's $X=IX=(I+AB)X -(AB)X$.

And this is true because we're adding and subtracting $ABX$.